# How to remove space from bootcamp partition and add it to Mac

Tags: macos, mac, partitioning, boot-camp

I'm currently in the same situation of this [https://superuser.com/questions/816666/increasing-mac-partition-after-shrink-windows-bootcamp-partition#*=*](https://superuser.com/questions/816666/increasing-mac-partition-after-shrink-windows-bootcamp-partition#_=_)

I've used MiniTool Partition Wizard to increase my bootcamp partition and now i need to take them back, I've tried to resize bootcamp partition and leave an empty partition that i could alloc using Mac disk utility but as noted on the above post, Windows cannot handle more than 4 partitions on disk

What possible way allows me to increase mac's partition from bootcamp without deleting/reinstalling anything ?

Comment: The golden rule is never let Windows touch the partitioning in Boot Camp - It simply doesn't understand how the volume is 'fooled' into thinking it has a certain structure. As mentioned in the linked answer iPartition is the safest way - though it cannot handle Core Storage [LVG] drives yet.

Comment: I've just answered that question (albeit late). You haven't presented enough details for me to be sure, but you may have created the sort of highly dangerous layout I note in that answer. I recommend you back up, study the ugly mess that is a hybrid MBR, and attempt a recovery based on that knowledge and the details of your layout. If you need more help, post detailed information on both your GPT and MBR partition tables.